# GAE Python URI path

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm using App Engine to make a very simple HTTP GET request, using the urllib2 library.

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
response = opener.open('http://api.server.com/v1/task')
```

Extremely simple stuff. The problem is google is modifying the URI and sending the full path instead of `/v1/tasks` as the URI. This is actually causing a problem on another server (tornado) which expects a URI to be passed as a relative path not an absolute URL.

I tested this locally and native Python urllib2 does not pass a URI with the full path, Google is doing something to the urllib2 library. Not cool.

Comment: If it's on another server, it should be using absolute path. Relative path mean it's on the current server.

Comment: `urllib2` is being used as a wrapper around `urlfetch`. To use native `urllib2` you may try to force enable sockets in app.yaml: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/#making_httplib_use_sockets